# When window can be undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When object window can be undefined ?

I look on custom hook of useLocalStorage and what meaning of checking window typeof ?
When it can be undefined

Example hook:

```
function useLocalStorage(key, initialValue) {
  // State to store our value
  // Pass initial state function to useState so logic is only executed once
  const [storedValue, setStoredValue] = useState(() => {
    if (typeof window === "undefined") {
      return initialValue;
    }
    try {
      // Get from local storage by key
      const item = window.localStorage.getItem(key);
      // Parse stored json or if none return initialValue
      return item ? JSON.parse(item) : initialValue;
    } catch (error) {
      // If error also return initialValue
      console.log(error);
      return initialValue;
    }
  });
  // Return a wrapped version of useState's setter function that ...
  // ... persists the new value to localStorage.
  const setValue = (value) => {
    try {
      // Allow value to be a function so we have same API as useState
      const valueToStore =
        value instanceof Function ? value(storedValue) : value;
      // Save state
      setStoredValue(valueToStore);
      // Save to local storage
      if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
        window.localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(valueToStore));
      }
    } catch (error) {
      // A more advanced implementation would handle the error case
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
  return [storedValue, setValue];
}
```

Comment: In background workers, there is no window object defined. See the JS Worker definition.

Comment: Also when you render on server, there is no window object. And maybe there are also test setups without window object.

Answer (score 1):

This condition

```js
if (typeof window === "undefined") {}
```

is a typical check that your code is executed in a browser. A browser has window object and => has localStorage object.